# Add Field as Entity in Group Module

Tags: entities, files, group

The group module is an alternative to the og module.  The og module allows you to assign permissions to fields per group.  I would like to be able to do the same thing with the group module.  It appears that in order to do this, I need to add a field or fields as an entity in the Group module. All my searches seem to indicate that the GroupContentEnabler plugin will enable me to do this. But I can't find any clear example of how. Can someone point me to some documentation on how to go about coding this?

[image]

Follow up:

It appears that hook_entity_field_access() will allow me to do what I wish to do.  I found an example of it's use in the group module:

This is the code used in group.module (not gnode.module):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_field_access().
 *
 * {@inheritdoc}
 *
 * @todo Move this to a form controller so we can hide the field if it has no
 *       options available to it?
 */
function group_entity_field_access($operation, FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition, AccountInterface $account, FieldItemListInterface $items = NULL) {
  // Can't retrieve an entity from an empty item list.
  if (!isset($items)) {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }

  // We only care about the group_roles field when on a form.
  if ($field_definition->getName() != 'group_roles' || $operation !== 'edit') {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }

  **// We only care if it is attached to a group content entity.
  if ($items->getEntity()->getEntityTypeId() != 'group_content') {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }**

  /** @var \Drupal\group\Entity\GroupContentInterface $group_content */
  $group_content = $items->getEntity();

  // We only care if the group content entity is a group membership.
  if ($group_content->getContentPlugin()->getPluginId() != 'group_membership') {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }

  // Now that we know we're dealing with a group_roles field on a group
  // membership form, we need to check whether the group membership belongs to a
  // group yet. If not, we can't check for access and should always hide it.
  if (!$group = $group_content->getGroup()) {
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

  // Only group administrators should be able to change the membership roles.
  return AccessResult::forbiddenIf(!$group->hasPermission('administer members', $account));
}
```

It appears that all I have to do is create a group permission, then check access to the field in question against that permission using hook_entity_field_access().

My only question is with this code:

```
// We only care if the group content entity is a group membership.
  if ($group_content->getContentPlugin()->getPluginId() != 'group_membership') {
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }
```

Let's say I create a custom field called "my_test_field".  And, I create a group permission called "access test field".  I then change above code:

```
// We only care about the the my_test_field field.
          if ($field_definition->getName() != 'my_test_field'
...
...
// Only users with 'access test field' should be able to see my_test_field.
  return AccessResult::forbiddenIf(!$group->hasPermission('access test field, $account));
```

If this field is attached to a node that is in a group, I am assuming that it is now attached to the group node entity.  But what about this?:

```
 if ($group_content->getContentPlugin()->getPluginId() != 'group_membership') {
```

Is the field also now automatically a group membership?  I guess I don't understand what that means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you would approach this by adding the fields as entities via the `GroupContentEnabler` (that'd mean one custom plugin per field? Given a large number of fields that *might* not be the best solution). However, for an example how to implement your own custom group-content-type plugin see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/259674/how-to-add-custom-entities-to-group-types/266681#266681).

Another possible approach that might be worth checking is to implement `hook_entity_field_access()` to define access checks for single fields programmatically (that's how I've solved a similar problem). See the group module's `gnode.module` file for an example how to check permissions/roles for users and add cache-tags to access results.

Comment: Thank you.  I have modified my question to try and understand how to use hook_entity_field_access() to restrict access to a field attached to a group node.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to load the group content from the node to which the field entity is attached.

// This field is a node entity
$node = $items->getEntity(); 
$type = $node->bundle(); 
$group_content_types = GroupContentType::loadByContentPluginId("group_node:$type"); 
$group_content = reset($group_contents);

This same logic also works for paragraph fields, with this additional code:

// This field is a paragraph entity
  $onode = $items->getEntity();
  $otype = $onode->bundle(); // original type (paragraph)
  // Get the parent entity of the paragraph, which is a node
  $node = $onode->getParentEntity();
  $type = $node->bundle(); // new type (node)
  $group_content_types = GroupContentType::loadByContentPluginId("group_node:$type"); 
  $group_content = reset($group_contents);